# Le sens de l'expression «pousser du coude»

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

«(...) se poussaint du coude en le montrant du doigt avec ravissement».

[Selon ce site internet](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/66011), je trouve que le sens de «pousser du coude» est

> Signaler qqchose à qqun par un coup de coude, signe de connivence
>   (souvent moqueuse, railleuse) ; geste pour attirer l'attention de qqun

Alors, dans la phrase l'action de pousser du coude, n'est pas vraiment une poussée(?) du coude, mais l'action de lui montrer le doigt. Est-ce que j'ai raison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non, on ne montre pas (nécessairement) du doigt quand on pousse du coude.

On tape discrètement avec la pointe du coude le côté de l'abdomen de la personne située à côté de soi, un peu comme pour le chatouiller.

Answer (score 3):

La poussée du coude est un véritable signal transmis via le coude, signal qui se veut habituellement plus discret qu'un autre émis avec la voix, et destiné à attirer l'attention en douce, mais qui est souvent combiné, dans la vraie vie tout comme dans l'exemple soumis, à un geste bien moins discret du doigt, qui en nullifie un peu le but. Les plus discrets opteront plutôt pour une indication par un léger mouvement dirigé des sourcils ou du menton, qui pourra la plupart du temps être assez explicite pour diriger l'attention dans la direction voulue.

On pourra néanmoins comprendre l'exemple proposé dans la question comme un autre usage de ce même signal par le coude, lequel remplace avantageusement la voix dans une foule bruyante. Le signalement clair et sans ambiguïté d'une chose considérée comme digne d'intérêt, et non la discrétion, est le but recherché de l'exercice. De la même manière, montrer du doigt aide à préciser la position de la chose considérée.

La voix à volume normal n'étant parfois d'aucune aide dans le tumulte ambiant d'une foule, ce genre de communication physique évite de devoir crier pour transmettre un message.

Answer (score 0):

Signalons qu'il existe deux expressions voisines ayant un sens très différent:

- *pousser du coude* désigne un petit signal de connivence que l'on envoie à un proche en le tapotant avec son coude, ce qui équivaut à un clin d’œil, tandis que
- *jouer des coudes* indique celui qui, dans une foule, agresse par des coups de coude ceux qui sont devant lui afin de se frayer un chemin vers la tête de la foule en les forçant à bouger sous l'effet de la petite douleur qu'il leur inflige.